# How can I run all the targets in an Ant buildfile?

Tags: ant

I would like to execute all targets instead of specifying each one.

For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="Kte" default="all" basedir="/home/Kte">

    <target name="target1">
    </target>

    <target name="target2">
    </target>
</project>
```

Currently I have use:

```
$ ant target1
$ ant target2
```

I'd like to use:

```
$ ant
```

and have both targets get built  (this is just an example. Reality I have a long ever changing Ant buildfile with sub-ant files so would be very handy to have an "all" feature.

Answer (score 24):

You could create an ant task all, which depends on all the specific targets that you have...

```
<target name="all" depends="target1, target2, ... ">
</target>

ant all
```

Comment: Thanks for that idea. I'm planning on adding these targets dynamically and was hoping only to add a new target and the next time it builds it will include the new target.

Answer (score 4):

You can also set up a default task that will run when you just type ant.  The default attribute is in the project element.

```
<project name="foo" default="all">
  <target name="all" depends="target1, target2"/>
  <target name="target1">
   ...
  </target>
  <target name="target2">
   ...
  </target>
</project>

$ ant
```

Answer (score 2):

Because Ant is declarative it doesn't do this sort of thing nicely.  You might consider a [`script` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/script.html) though.

Ant buildfiles have an implicit un-named target that 'holds' all the tasks that are not part of named targets.  So this, placed at the top-level, would do what you describe.

```
<script language="javascript"><![CDATA[
    importClass( java.util.Vector );

    vec = new Vector( project.getTargets().keySet() );
    vec.setSize( vec.size( ) - 1 );
    project.executeTargets( vec );
]]>
</script>
```

(The implicit target appears at the end of the list, hence the size adjustment to prevent recursion.)

If you put that script in a 'runner' target - which would execute all other targets in the buildfile - you would need to remove the 'runner' from the Vector (and the implicit target-with-no-name) to prevent recursion.

Comment: Great solution! I didn't like assuming the implicit target, so I used vec.remove(...) to remove a few specific targets.

Comment: Thanks, but project.getTargets() doesn't respect ordering. Example: clean, compile, jar, run, <implicit> -> clean, jar (fails)

Comment: I think Raghuram's solution would be more appropriate if the set of targets has dependencies.  Also avoids use of javascript.